# How can I organize the routes in routes.yml?

Tags: symfony

I started converting a legacy app over to symfony, my first experience with a php framework was zend, learning zend 1.* to a point where I felt comfortable took me over a year, now I've challenged myself to learn symfony since I find zend 2.* overly complicated.

With zend I was used to just creating a controller class and the view to create a page. With symfony I have to create the route entry, then the controller class and finally the view.

My routes.yml is over 100 lines long with all the requirements, methods and whatnot, and I am about a third into the project.

How can I keep this file organized? Right now it looks very chaotic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site should be split into bundles that represent the section of the site that it concerns (from the site I am currently working on)

```
AddressingBundle
ChartBundle
ContactBundle
CoreBundle        // A bundle that contains all merging items (model, types, etc)
CustomerBundle
PaymentBundle
PolicyBundle
.. etc ...
```

NOTE: I use YAML for routing. Annotation are available that require no extra files but (possible) means lack of reusability of routes

Within each of those bundles is a set of routing files that can be included or not. Each bundle has a routing file located at `Resources/config/routing.yml` that links to a selection of files located in `Resources/config/routing/`.

Then for the main `app/config/routing.yml` file I can then link to the outer (`Resources/config/routing.yml`) or internal (`Resources/config/routing/something.yml`) as needs be. Also it enables you to use the same routes multiples times using different paths depending on prefixes.

***UPDATE***:
The idea of bundles is to separate concerns. So for me I have (which I have massive stolen from the make up of Sylius) the CustomerBundle that only has a single entity (Customer), then I have the AddressingBundle with a single entity (Address). These can work alone but are attached using the data in CoreBundle. This way if I need to edit the Customer section I just edit CustomerBundle and make sure it interacts in the same way. Technically there is not public and private bundles (due to them all being below root), there are only routes that you make public via your routing and security.

Comment: My project will have a public bundle to be accessed by visitors so I thought I was going to need only two bundles: AdminBundle and PublicBundle but based on your answer to just handle the administrative tasks for the admin bundle I should create even more, is that correct?

Comment: Glad to help. I have found the Sylius source a great place to learn from once I got past the basics. It, as is every other new piece of source code, horrible to work through at first but when it makes sense it REALLY makes sense - https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius